# AvroMultipleOutputs creates empty file no error in logs

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, avro

Trying to write output into two different named output file using 
AvroMultipleOutputs but getting an empty file and no error in the logs. Counter shows correct number of records. Also this
works fine when writing to a single file.

Avro version 1.7.1

Code

```
Job job = new Job(config, "AVRO_MULTITEST");
job.setJarByClass(AvroMultiWriter.class);

FileInputFormat.setInputPaths(job, new Path(args[0]));
FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(args[1]));

job.setInputFormatClass(TextInputFormat.class);
job.setOutputFormatClass(AvroKeyValueOutputFormat.class);
job.setMapperClass(AvroMultiWriteMapper.class);
job.setNumReduceTasks(0);


AvroJob.setOutputKeySchema(job, Schema.create(Schema.Type.STRING));
AvroJob.setOutputValueSchema(job, Schema.create(Schema.Type.STRING));
AvroJob.setMapOutputKeySchema(job, Schema.create(Schema.Type.STRING));
AvroJob.setMapOutputValueSchema(job, Schema.create(Schema.Type.STRING));

AvroMultipleOutputs.setCountersEnabled(job, true);
AvroMultipleOutputs.addNamedOutput(job,"F1",
        AvroKeyValueOutputFormat.class, Schema.create
(Schema.Type.STRING),Schema.create(Schema.Type.STRING));

AvroMultipleOutputs.addNamedOutput(job,"F2",
        AvroKeyValueOutputFormat.class, Schema.create
(Schema.Type.STRING),Schema.create(Schema.Type.STRING));

LazyOutputFormat.setOutputFormatClass(job, AvroKeyValueOutputFormat.class);
```

Job Counter

```
mapred.JobClient:   org.apache.avro.mapreduce.AvroMultipleOutputs
mapred.JobClient:     F1=3
mapred.JobClient:     F2=3
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried calling `multipleOutputs.close()` in the `close()` method of the mapper class?